# 1 Extra count is showing in the Results

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, jquery-pagination

I am using pajinate() j query plugin to paginate my results. But it Always show 1 Extra count on paginating div for example: [image: Error]

```
function DisplayLawyerData(lawyers) {
        if (!lawyers)
            return;
   var source = $("#Lawyerrowtemplate").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        var html = template(lawyers);
        $("#rec").show();
        $("#rec").append(html);
        $('#Records').pajinate({
            num_page_links_to_display: 10,
            items_per_page: 10,
       nav_panel_id: '.alt_page_navigation'
        });
    }
```

Comment: Provide some code for that...